# Route to user account after user login

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have created a log in component in ReactJS. The user can log in with their email and password. I want the user to route to his user account after a successful login. I have used JWT authentication and authentication occurs properly.

Is there a way to get data from API after login? If I could get userId from the server I can route to the user account. But I have no idea how yo get the relevant user data with the login of user. How can I do this?

This is my login component, Login.js:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

    state = {};
    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const logingdata ={
            email : this .Email,
            password: this .Password
        }
           axios
           .post('/api/UserLogin', logingdata)

           .then(response => {
               console.log(response); //to print response in console in developper tool
               //const currentuser = JSON.parse(atob(response.data.token.split(".")[1])); 
               localStorage.setItem('login', response.data.token);
               console.log(this.email);
               
           })
           .catch(error => {
               console.log(error => console.log(error.response.data))
           })
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <div className="outer">
            <div className="inner"> 
            <form onSubmit={ this.submitHandler}>

                <h3>Log in</h3>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" onChange ={ e => this.Email = e.target.value} />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" onChange ={ e => this.Password = e.target.value} />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 
                
                
                <br></br>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">Sign in</button>
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Forgot <Link to= "/Forgotpassword" >password?</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

LoginContoller:

```
 public class UserLoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly PharmacyDataContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private IJWTService _jwtService;

        public UserLoginController(IConfiguration config, IJWTService jwtservice, PharmacyDataContext context)
        {
            _config = config;
            _context = context;
            _jwtService = jwtservice;
        }


        // POST: api/UserLogin
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin(Login login)
        {
            try
            {

                var CheckCustomeEmil = _context.Customer.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email.ToLower() == login.Email);
                var CheckCustomerPW = _context.Customer.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Password.ToLower() == login.Password);


                var CheckPharmacyEmail = _context.Pharmacy.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email.ToLower() == login.Email);
                var CheckPharmacyPW = _context.Pharmacy.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Password.ToLower() == login.Password);


                if (((CheckCustomeEmil == null) || (CheckCustomerPW == null)) && ((CheckPharmacyEmail == null) || (CheckPharmacyPW == null)))
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                else
                {
                    var tokenString = _jwtService.GenerateJWTtoken(login);
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        token = tokenString
                    });
                }

            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            { throw ex; }

        }

    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. You have your token stored locally, so basically, if you also own the backend, you could put relefant user data in there. Also once you're logged in, you probably have to send the token along with every request to the API to authenticate.

Comment: I want to get the userID back from the API according to the login input details.

Comment: Can you also include the API route in the backend to authenticate the user? This is likely a backend discussion

Comment: @alexYepes  Thank you. I updated the question with backend code.

Comment: Can you also include the route where you use the controller?

Comment: There is a downvoted answer which suggests including the uid in the token. You could go that route and decode the token on the front end. You would secure your token with some kind of public-private key signature. Anyway, I guess the uid is in one of those Objects you authenticate again. If you do not want to include that in the token, send it back after authentication as the response body, in a cookie, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Usually, userId comes inside JWT.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

function getUserIdFromRawToken(raw) {
  const token = jwt.decode(raw, { complete: true });
  const userId = token.payload.sub
  return userId
}
```